# Bootstrap 3 - Highlight table row when hovering over a certain row in another table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have two tables that will be placed side-by-side:

```
<table id="Table1" class="table table-hover">
    <tbody>
       <tr>
           <td>Col 1</td>
           <td>Col 2 </td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<table id="Table2" class="table table-hover">
    <tbody>
       <tr>
           <td>Col 1</td>
           <td>Col 2 </td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to make the row highlighting effect on mouse hover to work across the rows so that it appears as if they are the same table. I.e. When the user's curser is over Col 2 in table 1, then Col-2 in table one will also appear to be highlighted.

There are no classes added to the markup when highlighted so I don't think that I can use an on-hover event to then apply the class across the rest of the rows using jQuery.

Please note that I am using Bootstrap 3.0.3.

Comment: onhover is your only option; you may have to modify your markup to give you a way to tell which row is being highlighted so you can highlight the corresponding row in the other table

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$('#Table1 tbody tr td').mouseover(function(){
    var ro=$(this).closest('tr').index()
    var col=$(this).index()
    $(this).addClass('hov').siblings().removeClass('hov')
    $('#Table2 tr:eq('+ro+')').find('td:eq('+col+')').addClass('hov').siblings().removeClass('hov')
});
$('#Table1 tbody tr td').mouseleave(function(){
    var ro=$(this).closest('tr').index()
    var col=$(this).index()
    $(this).removeClass('hov')
    $('#Table2 tr:eq('+ro+')').find('td:eq('+col+')').removeClass('hov')
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9LCdw/4/)